# How to cluster a sparse adjacency matrix using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, visualization

I have a 40000*40000 sparse connectivity matrix which represents my graph and I used a normalized cut algorithm to cluster this graph. After the clustering, I get the partition tags for each node as a 40000*1 array.

What is the best way to represent this matrix as a cluster matrix where value of each (i,j) i.e the connections between clusters will be represented. Basically if I have 20 clusters, I will need to have a 20*20 matrix where each element is the total of connections between clusters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding the number of connections **from** cluster `a` **to** cluster `b` should be fairly simple:

```
cluster_connections(a,b) = nnz(connectivity_matrix(tags==a, tags==b));
```

Here's an example using a full matrix solely for readability. A sparse matrix will behave the same way.

```
>> connectivity_matrix = randi([0 1],10)
connectivity_matrix =

   1   1   0   0   0   1   1   0   1   1
   0   0   1   0   1   1   1   1   0   1
   0   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   1
   0   1   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1
   1   1   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   1
   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   1   1
   1   1   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   1
   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   1   0   1
   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   1   1
   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1

>> tags = [1 2 3 2 3 1 2 3 3 1]
tags =

   1   2   3   2   3   1   2   3   3   1


>> connectivity_matrix(tags==2, tags==3)
ans =

   1   1   1   0
   0   1   1   1
   0   0   1   0

>> cluster_connections = nnz(connectivity_matrix(tags==2, tags==3))
cluster_connections =  7
```